# How to program an application that values of fields of some tables put nestedly into some arbitrary tags

Tags: c#

i have a university project in c# such that:
    A)we have a database of some tables.
    B) values of fields of these tables must be put into particular tags such that these tags are arbitrary. Sample example is on this page below.
 Pay attention to this statement that, "tags" are fictional(arbitrary) hence, you can create whatever tags that these tags are abbreviations of some words of fields of your table.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Show any kind of effort

Comment: <X>

<PH>

<SQ>1</SQ> <ND>870301</ND> <RD> 870304</RD> <VD>881229</VD> <KD>870229</KD> <PT>105</PT> <SN>1164621341-0</SN><GR>1</GR> <RN>12</RN> <PG>1</PG><PC>12034</PC> <PP>50000</PP> <IS> 3500 </IS> <PS> 1500 </PS>

</PH>

<BY>

<MH><SG>21</SG> <MG>0069123</MG> <MD>5 </MD> <MP>50000 </MP> <MI>3500</MI> <MS> 1500 </MS> </MH>

</BY>

</X>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't gave any particular code I'll just use imaginary code samples.

First when you retrieve your object from the database ( `var entities = DAL.GetAllEntities()` ) you should iterate through each `Entity` ( `foreach(Entity entity in entities)`. Then inside the `foreach` loop you can just add tags ( `string.Format("<n>{0}</n>", entity.GeorgeClooney)` ). Remembering to add start and end tags ( `string startTag = "<h>", endTag = "</h>";` )

Combining all of those in code snippet you have something like :

```
string PackIntoTags(IEnumerable<Entity> entitites)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var enumerator = entities.GetEnumerator();
    while ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
    {
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        result += "<h>";
        result += string.Format("<n>{0}</n>", entity.GeorgeClooney);
        restul += string.Format<"<sq>{0}</sq>", entity.twenieth_revord_of_the_table);
        result += "</h>";
    }
}
```

There are different approaches using `Reflection` and custom `Attribute`s as an example would be somewhat easier to implement if you have more than one `Entity` type. But I can now only speculate because **you've shown too less details**.

Comment: Thanks dear friends, i have some tags that are like this 

<X>

<PH>

<SQ>1</SQ> <ND>870301</ND> <RD> 870304</RD> <VD>881229</VD> <KD>870229</KD> <PT>105</PT> <SN>1164621341-0</SN><GR>1</GR> <RN>12</RN> <PG>1</PG><PC>12034</PC> <PP>50000</PP> <IS> 3500 </IS> <PS> 1500 </PS>

</PH>

<BY>

<MH><SG>21</SG> <MG>0069123</MG> <MD>5 </MD> <MP>50000 </MP> <MI>3500</MI> <MS> 1500 </MS> </MH>

</BY>

</X>